# Routing issues with custom route in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

My controller structure (api is the folder inside controller)

```
controllers/api/Api_1_0.php
controllers/api/Api_2_0.php
```

In my routes.php

```
$route['api/(\d+)\.(\d+)']          = "api/Api_$1_$2";
$route['api/(\d+)\.(\d+)/(:any)']   = "api/Api_$1_$2/$3";
```

The routing strategy i need is, if **/api/2.0** is specified it will point to controller file **Api_2_0.php**

ie. api/**x**.**y** points to file Api_**x**_**y**.php

Everything working fine with above routing but below is my issue:

```
https://www.example.com/api/2.0/photos/1234567890 // not working

https://www.example.com/api/2.0/photos // working
```

How to solve ?

Comment: Either helps or not change the order of those routes. Most specific routes should be placed first. According to docs you wrote correct code there. Also, follow all advices and recommendations like default routes at the beginning of `routes.php` file. As rule of thumb, follow standardization from docs. Saying that, try with lower cases for controller name in right hand side of route. After all of these mentioned, next in order what I would try is URL with `index.php` in it. And of course, you should give us error you are getting. But controller code would be helpful too.

Comment: @Tpojka: could you please provide me an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment you should change the order.

But you should also change (:any) to (.*). (:any) would only match first segment of your url.

So correct way would be:

```
$route['api/(\d+)\.(\d+)/(.*)']   = "api/api_$1_$2/$3";
$route['api/(\d+)\.(\d+)']        = "api/api_$1_$2";
```